# Hbase table duplication

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, duplicates, hbase

There is a way to duplicate table data on every node of a cluster?
I need to do a performance test with the maximum grade of locality of the data.
By default, HBase distributes data on a small fraction of the cluster nodes (on 1 or 2 nodes), maybe because my data isn't very big-data ( ~ 2 GB ).
I know that Hbase is designed for much larger data sets, but in this case, it is a requirement for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of nice reads* about it (see the end of the post) but I'll try to explain it with my own words ;)

HBase is not responsible of data replication, the Hadoop HDFS is, and by default is configured with a replication factor of 3, that means all data will be stored in at least 3 nodes.

Data locality is a key aspect to get good performance, but achieving maximum data locality is easy: **you only need to colocate your HBase Regionservers (RS) along to the Hadoop Datanodes (DN)**, so, all your DN should have also the RS role. Once you have that, HBase will automatically move the data where it's needed (on major compactions) to achieve data locality and that's all, as long as each RS has the data of the regions it serves locally you'll have data locality.

**Even when you have the data replicated to multiple DN, each region (and the rows they contain) will be served by just one RS**, it doesn't matter you have a replication factor of 3, 10 or 100... Reading a row belonging to the region #1 will always hit the same RS, and that will be the one that hosts the region (which will read the data locally from the HDFS because of data locality). If the RS hosting that region goes down, the region will be assigned to another RS automatically (because the data is also replicated to other DN)

---

What you can do is to split your table in a way each RS has even buckets of rows (regions) assigned to it, so as much different RS as possible work simultaneously when you read or write data, increasing your overall throughput as long as you don't always hit the same regions (called regionserver hotspotting**).

Therefore, you should always start by ensuring that all the regions of your table are assigned to different RS and they receive the same volume of R/W requests. Once you've done that you can split your table into more regions once until you have an even number of regions on all the RS of your cluster (you may need to assign them manually if you're not happy with the load balancer).

Just remind that even when you seem to have a perfect distribution of regions you can still have poor performance if your data access pattern is not right (or it's uneven) and doesn't reach all regions evenly, in the end it all depends on your application.

---

(*) Recommended reads:

- http://www.larsgeorge.com/2009/10/hbase-architecture-101-storage.html
- http://www.larsgeorge.com/2010/05/hbase-file-locality-in-hdfs.html

(**) To avoid RS hotspotting we always design our tables to have non-monotonically increasing row keys, so rows 1, 2, 3 ... N are hosted different regions, the common approach is to use the MD5(id) + id as rowkey. This approach has it's own set of drawbacks: you cannot scan the first 10 rows because they're salted.